# Networks plugin missing from QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, network, vector-layer, graph

I installed the Networks plugin in QGIS 3.4.7 successfully, but it does not appear in the Vector Tab.

Can anyone suggest another way to reverse the direction of a vector used in a network (graph)?

Answer (score 4):

**How to install and use a QGIS plugin**

1. Install the plugin from the Plugin Manager. Close the Plugin Manager without reading the plugin description.
2. Spend 5-10 minutes searching QGIS for the plugin interface.

- Is it a new toolbar/menu/panel?
- Is it a new button on an existing toolbar?
- Is it a new item or section in an existing menu?

3. Return to the Plugin Manager. Search the plugin description for some mention of where to find the plugin interface. Realize that the description doesn't tell you where to find the plugin interface.
4. Return to step 2 and repeat *ad nauseum* or until the end of the workday, whichever comes first.

---

**The Networks plugin adds a new section to the Processing Toolbox:**

[image]

This is a weird place for a plugin interface. They really should mention that in the plugin description.

Answer (score 1):

**NETWORKS PLUGIN**

As shown in Answer 1 the Networks shortcut plugin really is in the Processing Toolbox, with many tools including Reverse Arcs.
But the Reverse Arcs tool reverses the direction of the entire network.

On May 3, 2019 the **Reverse Selection Geometries** tool was included in this plugin. This new tool reverses selected arcs, saving changes into the same layer in edition.
[image]

**REVERSE ARC DIRECTION TOOL**

This tool, found in Processing Toolbox, reverses the entire network or reverses just the selected arcs, always creating a new layer and a new file.
If someone chooses to revert only a few selected arcs, the output file will include just these in the new layer and in the new file, this can be cumbersome for large networks.

**SWAP VECTOR DIRECTION PLUGIN**

The Vector Direction Swap plugin seems to be a good alternative to reverse the direction of only the selected vectors.
This plugin does not create a new layer or file, it edits the active layer itself.
The shortcut for this plugin can be found in the Vector tab.

[image]

To reverse some network arcs: enable the layer, select the arcs of interest, click Reverse Direction of Geometry.
Then save your changes and close the vector editing.